# Alpine correct way of using key event handlers inside of the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to build a simple app where you can use the arrow keys to do certain things. And trying to get the front end to react appropriately. But so far, I'v not been able to update the data inside x-data.

Simple flow

- Press ArrowUp key
- keyDownHandler triggered
- upPressed set to true
- ArrowUp key released
- keyUpHandler triggered
- upPressed set to false
  again.

But this is not working since the event handler can't set this.upPressed from where it is registered.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div x-data="loadComponent()" x-init="init">
    Right: <span x-text="rightPressed"></span><br>
    Left: <span x-text="leftPressed"></span><br>
    Up: <span x-text="upPressed"></span><br>
    Down: <span x-text="downPressed"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function loadComponent() {
    return {
        rightPressed: false,
        leftPressed: false,
        upPressed: false,
        downPressed: false,
    init: function() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyDownHandler, false)
            document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyUpHandler, false)
    },
    keyUpHandler(e) {
      console.log(e.key) //loggin the key up event
      if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        this.rightPressed = false
      }
      else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        this.leftPressed = false
      }
      else if (e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp") {
        this.upPressed = false
      }
      else if (e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown") {
        this.downPressed = false
      }
        },
    keyDownHandler(e) {
      console.log(e.key) // login the key down event
      if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        this.rightPressed = true
      }
      else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        this.leftPressed = true
      }
      else if (e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp") {
        this.upPressed = true
      }
      else if (e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown") {
        this.downPressed = true
      }
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the object to a variable, and reference that, or, you can wrap the callback such that `this` will be your object (provided `init` is called with the correct `this`).

For the second solution:

```
init: function() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", e => this.keyDownHandler(e), false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", e => this.keyUpHandler(e), false);
}
```